# python - replace string within larger corpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm looking for a native python solution that would allow me to replace phrases wherever they appear within a list of strings. Basically, this looks like:

```
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric','guitar','fender guitar','PRS electric',...]
```

And I'm aiming to locate phrases (exactly) in `text_array` and replace them with the string logic I have mapped out in a dict that I'm calling `thesaurus`:

```
thesaurus = {'gibson model':'guitar', 'fender guitar':'guitar', 'PRS electric':'guitar'}
```

### Question

How would I iterate over each element of `text_array` and replace all occurrences, wherever they appear, of phrases flagged in `thesaurus`? (Note: I just want to replace exact matches and leave the rest of the string in-tact).

Desired output:

```
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this guitar or this guitar', 'guitar','guitar','guitar']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my approach. This one doesn't affect the original `text_array`.

```
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric','guitar','fender guitar','PRS electric']
thesaurus = {'gibson model':'guitar', 'fender guitar':'guitar', 'PRS electric':'guitar'}

res = []
for text in text_array:
    for key in thesaurus:
        text = text.replace(key, thesaurus[key])
    res.append(text)
print(res)
```

Comment: Seems to be working for the most part, but in some instances words are removed altogether. As in `text_array.count('guitar')` returns `0`. I don't think it's other parts of my code, still trying to debug though. Let me know if anything comes to mind in terms of this snippet.

Comment: @ArashHowaida What is the exact problem you're facing? Can you post an example? Note that `count` counts the number of elements that are equal to the argument. It will not count occurrences in substrings, e.g. `["guitar store", "guitar"].count("guitar")` will return `1`, because the complete string `"guitar"` only occurs once.

Comment: It's probably user error haha, I'll post another one down the road if it persists. It's just one part of the data set anyway that has lots of similar configurations of the same words. Instead of going missing, it now actually seems to be not keeping the `thesaurus` mapping for some reason.  (i.e. still occurrences of `fender guitar`) Again nothing major, 90% of data seems to be remapped correctly.

Comment: @BenjiaminRuck Fixed it. For some reason it couldn't handle keys that were portions of other keys. Like in my real data set I had things like `fender guitar gibson` or maybe it was something else altogether, a bit over my head atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet, to get the expected output:

```py
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric','guitar','fender guitar','PRS electric',...]

thesaurus = {'gibson model':'guitar', 'fender guitar':'guitar', 'PRS electric':'guitar'}


for index, val in enumerate(text_array):
    # Checking if key exist in list item

    for key in list(thesaurus.keys()):
        if key in val:
            # Updating List item value
            text_array[index] = text_array[index].replace(key, thesaurus[key])
```

Comment: Looks good! You can omit the `for key in list(thesaurus.keys()):` and just write `for key in thesaurus:` instead.

Comment: No need to use `if key in val:` as replace function takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric','guitar','fender guitar','PRS electric']
thesaurus = {'gibson model':'guitar', 'fender guitar':'guitar', 'PRS electric':'guitar'}
for key in thesaurus.keys():
    for i,item in enumerate(text_array):
        text_array[i]=item.replace(key,thesaurus[key])
print(text_array)
```

Result :

```
['the store has a piano', 'dulcimer players are popular with the ladies', 'guitar', 'rock legends dont shy away from this guitar or this guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar']
```

Comment: Should the last part be `result_array`?

Comment: I have edited the code now. `result_array' is not needed. You can modify it a little if you want to preserve the original array as @Benjamin Ruck approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine :

```
text_array = ['the store has a piano','dulcimer players are popular with the ladies','guitar','rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric','guitar','fender guitar','PRS electric',]
thesaurus = {'gibson model':'guitar', 'fender guitar':'guitar', 'PRS electric':'guitar'}


for i in range(len(text_array)):
    for x,y in thesaurus.items():
            text_array[i] = text_array[i].replace(x,y)
            
                

print(text_array)
```

Output:

```
['the store has a piano', 'dulcimer players are popular with the ladies', 'guitar', 'rock legends dont shy away from this guitar or this guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, there's a single match, so we could use a generator expression inside `next` to search for a match in the "thesaurus":

If you want to change the original list:

```
for i, text in enumerate(text_array):
    m = next(((k,v) for k,v in thesaurus.items() if k in text), None)
    if m:
        text_array[i] = text.replace(m[0], m[1])
```

If you want to create a new list:

```
for i, text in enumerate(text_array):
    m = next(((k,v) for k,v in thesaurus.items() if k in text), None)
    if m:
        text = text.replace(m[0], m[1])
    out.append(text)
```

You can also use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(text_array)
msk = s.str.contains('|'.join(thesaurus))
s[msk] = s[msk].replace(thesaurus, regex=True)
out = s.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['the store has a piano',
 'dulcimer players are popular with the ladies',
 'guitar',
 'rock legends dont shy away from this guitar',
 'guitar',
 'guitar',
 'guitar']
```

Comment: this is quite good, actually. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

text_array = [
    'the store has a piano',
    'dulcimer players are popular with the ladies',
    'guitar',
    'rock legends dont shy away from this gibson model or this PRS electric',
    'guitar',
    'fender guitar',
    'PRS electric'
]

thesaurus = {
    'gibson model':'guitar',
    'fender guitar':'guitar',
    'PRS electric':'guitar'
}

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in thesaurus.keys()) + r')(?!\w)')

for i,sentence in enumerate(text_array):
    
    text_array[i] = pattern.sub(lambda x: thesaurus[x.group()], sentence)

print(text_array)
```

Output:

```
['the store has a piano', 'dulcimer players are popular with the ladies', 'guitar', 'rock legends dont shy away from this guitar or this guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar', 'guitar']
```